# html filter search within multiple child level ul li tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have following code, the problem is when i search for "Billy", I get all three "Billy", which is what I expect.

However when I search for "Bob", I am only getting Two parent level "Bob". why the search loop only searches for in every level Bill and not Bob?

Now,right now there is only one sub-list, this will increase to many. What I want is to perform search at all level

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
  <li>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to account for the nested `li` when hiding your elements. Right now if you watch the values being returned by `a.innerHTML` you'll see it gets Billy 4 times because of the nest. As a result, when you hide the parent `li` Billy gets hit on first, the child `li` containing Bob is also hidden.

Modified your snippet to reference the parent of the `a` instead of looking at all the `li` tags directly.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a.parentElement.style.display = "";
        } else {
            a.parentElement.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
  <li>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
<li><ul><li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
</ul></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Zack, but even this is limited to only one level of parent. so if we have sub-sub-level list, it won't work

Comment: Updated snippet to prove you wrong. 3 layers it still gets all 4 bobs.

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();  
    var ul = document.getElementById("myUL");      
    var li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        var name = li[i].innerHTML;
        var parent =li[i].parentElement;

        if(parent.tagName == "UL"){
            if (name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) >= 0) {
                li[i].style.display = '';
            }
            else{
                li[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
}
```